# How do I install my whenever task as a cron job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby-on-rails-5, whenever

I'm using Rails 5.  I wanted to run a task periodically, so I was reading about the "whenever" gem.  After installing it, I created the file ./config/schedule.rb with

```
# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever
set :environment, "development"

every 10.minutes
  rake "events:calc_index"
end
```

Unfortunately, when I try to install this in my system using "whenever --crontab", as I'm told I have to, I get this error

```
localhost:cindex davea$ whenever --update-crontab
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `instance_eval': config/schedule.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever.rb:12:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever.rb:12:in `cron'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:54:in `whenever_cron'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:107:in `updated_crontab'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:35:in `run'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:6:in `execute'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/whenever-0.9.7/bin/whenever:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/whenever:22:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/whenever:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Wha'ts the proper way to install my whenever cron job?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the docs, it seems you need to do: `every 10.minutes do`, not `every 10.minutes`.

Comment: Yup that solved it.

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted as answer in case you care to accept. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the docs, it seems you need to do: `every 10.minutes do`, not `every 10.minutes`.